# How to use factor analysis / PCA / regression for data having serial IV and DV?

Tags: multiple-regression, pca, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I have data regarding effect of a food chemical on blood and urine levels as well as effect on blood sugar and cholesterol. So I have following variables:

```
1. age
2. gender

3. food_level
4. blood_level
5. urine_level

6. blood_sugar
7. blood_cholesterol
```

The thinking is that food_level is likely to affect blood_level and urine_level and these MAY affect blood_sugar and blood_cholesterol. Age and gender may have a modifying effect on these responses.

How should I analyze this data: by multiple regression or by factor analysis/ principal component analysis? Thanks for your help.

Edit: On reading more, it appears to me that this may need structural equation modelling (SEM). I am not sure how to proceed. I will appreciate very much if you could write how to get started or point me to some good link that may be of help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SEM to account for the hierarchical structure, especially if you are interested in the relative importance of direct/indirect paths. But you'd still need to specify the hypothesized mechanism: eg urine level, at least if all readings are taken simultaneously, seems like a less important covariate, hardly a direct predictor of blood levels, unless you are testing specifically for the rate of elimination.  If the key response variable of interest is, say, blood sugar you could use ANCOVA for food level with other factors as covariates, or use MR.